# how to get select value for dropdown list inside listview items template?

Tags: development, list-view, sharepoint-on-prem

I am trying to get the select value in dropdown list which exist inside listview ItemTemplate ad below :

```
<asp:ListView ID="AssignedRequestsListView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="RequestCode"
      OnItemCommand="AssignedRequestsListView_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="AssignedRequestsListView_ItemDataBound">
      <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="col-sm-12">

                <p class="text-warning">
                  <strong>No Requests found 
                  </strong>
                </p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </EmptyDataTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
          <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItemIndex") %></td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="RequestDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RequestDate","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="ORAIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ORAID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="SPIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="CurrentLevelLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CurrentLevel") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>

          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="OvertimeDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OvertimeDate","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="EmpNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmpName") %>'></asp:Label>

          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="EmpNumberLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmpNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CauseOTLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CauseOT") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="<%# "#myModal" + Eval("RequestCode") %>">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="<%# "myModal"+Eval("RequestCode") %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="<%# "#myModal"+Eval("RequestCode") %>">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                      <%# Eval("EmpNumber") %> - <%# Eval("EmpName") %> -  <%# Eval("EmpPosition") %>
                    </h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ShiftCodeTextBox" class="control-label">Shift Code  :</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ShiftCodeTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("ShiftCode") %>' ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="TimeInTextBox" class="control-label">Time In:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TimeInTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("TimeIn") %>' ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="TimeOutTextBox" class="control-label">Time Out:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TimeOutTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("TimeOut") %>' ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="CFOTDropDownList" class="control-label">Cause for OT:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("CauseOT") %>' ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="OTReasonTextBox" class="control-label">Comments:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="OTReasonTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("OTReason") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="OverTimeRemarksTextBox" class="control-label">Emp Remarks:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="OverTimeRemarksTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("OverTimeRemarks") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                              <tr>
                                <th style="width: 50%">OTD</th>
                                <td>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="OTDTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("OTD") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th>OTN</th>
                                <td>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="OTNTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("OTN") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th>OTO</th>
                                <td>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="OTOTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("OTO") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th>OP</th>
                                <td>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="OPTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("OP") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th>OTDo</th>
                                <td>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="OTDoTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("OTDo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th>OTNo</th>
                                <td>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="OTNoTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("OTNo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th>OTOo</th>
                                <td>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="OTOOTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("OTOo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th>OTH</th>
                                <td>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="OTHTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("OTH") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <th>HPo</th>
                                <td>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="HPoTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("HPo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row"  runat="server" id="SENIORDIV">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="SENIORRemarksTextBox" class="control-label">Senior Remarks:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="SENIORRemarksTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("SENIORRemarks") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="TeamleaderDDL" class="control-label">Teamleader:</label>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="TeamleaderDropDownList" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:DropDownList>
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row"  runat="server" id="TeamLeaderDIV">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="TeamLeadRemarksTextBox" class="control-label">Teamleader Remarks:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TeamLeadRemarksTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("TeamLeadRemarks") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ManagerDropDownList" class="control-label">Manager:</label>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ManagerDropDownList" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row" runat="server" id="MANAGERDIV">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ManagerRemarksTextBox" class="control-label">Manager Remarks:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ManagerRemarksTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("ManagerRemarks") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row"  runat="server" id="DCEODVI">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="DCEORemarksTextBox" class="control-label">DCEO Remarks:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="DCEORemarksTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("DCEORemarks") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row" runat="server" id="CEODIV">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="CEORemarksTextBox" class="control-label">CEO Remarks:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="CEORemarksTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("CEORemarks") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="ApprovedLinkButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-sm" CommandName="Approve" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItemIndex") %>'>Approve</asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="ReEvaluateLinkButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-sm" CommandName="ReEvaluate" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ORAID") %>'>Re-Evaluate</asp:LinkButton>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cnacel</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="background-color: #fff">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>S.N</th>
              <th>Request Date</th>
              <th>OT Date</th>
              <th>Employee Name</th>
              <th>Employee No</th>
              <th>Cause OT</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </tr>
          </tbody>

        </table>
      </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

in behinde code :

I tried to get the value of that dropdownlist in all ways :

```
int CurrentIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        string hajjaj = e.Item.DataItemIndex.ToString();


        string Url = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
        // find Required Controls.
        //DropDownList TeamleaderDropDownList = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("TeamleaderDropDownList");
        DropDownList TeamleaderDropDownList = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("TeamleaderDropDownList");
        DropDownList TeamleaderDropDownList2 = (DropDownList)AssignedRequestsListView.Items[e.Item.DataItemIndex].FindControl("TeamleaderDropDownList");
        DropDownList TeamleaderDropDownList3 = (DropDownList)AssignedRequestsListView.Items[CurrentIndex].FindControl("TeamleaderDropDownList");
```

but no success, for full code :

```
protected void AssignedRequestsListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
```

{
int CurrentIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
string Url = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
DropDownList TeamleaderDropDownList = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("TeamleaderDropDownList");
DropDownList TeamleaderDropDownList2 = (DropDownList)AssignedRequestsListView.Items[e.Item.DataItemIndex].FindControl("TeamleaderDropDownList");
DropDownList TeamleaderDropDownList3 = (DropDownList)AssignedRequestsListView.Items[CurrentIndex].FindControl("TeamleaderDropDownList");
DropDownList ManagerDropDownList = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ManagerDropDownList");
Label SPIDLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("SPIDLabel");
TextBox SENIORRemarksTextBox = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("SENIORRemarksTextBox");
TextBox TeamLeadRemarksTextBox = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("TeamLeadRemarksTextBox");
int ItemID = int.Parse(SPIDLabel.Text);
string WFStatus = "";
if (e.CommandName == "Approve")
{
WFStatus = "APPROVED";

```
}

else if (e.CommandName == "ReEvaluate")
{
    WFStatus = "REJECTED";
}
try
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(Url, SPUserToken.SystemAccount))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPListItem Item = web.Lists[Constants.ListOvertimeRequests].GetItemById(ItemID);
            string currentApproverLevel = string.Empty;

            if (Item != null)
            {
            currentApproverLevel = Item["CurrentLevel"].ToString();
            if (Item["CurrentLevel"].ToString().Equals("SENIOR", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Item["SENIORRemarks"] = SENIORRemarksTextBox.Text;
                Item["BatchReady"] = "1";
                Item["WFCompleted"] = false;
                Item["CurrentApprover"] = TeamleaderDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();
                Item["CurrentLevel"] = "TEAMLEAD";
                Item["TeamLeader"] = TeamleaderDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();

            }
        
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            Item.Update();
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    using (Logging errorLog = new Logging())
    { errorLog.LogException(ex, "Overtime Review Request- Update-Request"); }
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this and will work

```
    protected void AssignedRequestsListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if (String.Equals(e.CommandName, "ReEvaluate"))
    {

      ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
      // this will gives you Row for your list items

      DropDownList ManagerDropDownList=(DropDownList)dataItem.FindControl("ManagerDropDownList");
    // you can find any control on row like this
      string YourValue=ManagerDropDownList.SelectedValue;
    }
}
```